# Como Abrir outro Form dando double click na celula

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho uma tabela chamada torneios que mostra o tipo de jogo, o nome do torneio e a data.

Eu quero que ao fazer *double click* na célula do tipo de jogo abrisse as equipas desse tipo de jogo.

```
private void Dgv1_CellMouseDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    EquipasLOL Tela = new EquipasLOL();
    Tela.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Olá @Jose. Edita a sua questão e coloque o seu código, caso contrário será difícil ajudar sem termos uma base!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o evento `MouseDoubleClick`. Verifique se é a coluna do "Tipo de Jogo" utilizando o `If`. Passe como parâmetro o `Id` do "Tipo de Jogo" e utilize-o na tela `EquipasLOL`.

```
private void Dgv1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(Dgv1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == Dgv1.Columns["NomeDaColunaDoTipoDeJogo"].Index)
    {
        EquipasLOL Tela = new EquipasLOL(Dgv1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ColunaComOIdDoTipoDeJogo"].Value);
        Tela.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o meu problema!